# C#:Conversion of Dictionary<String,String> to Dictionary<String, Dictionary<String,String>>

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, lambda

The First `Dictionary` is like

```
        Dictionary<String, String> ParentDict = new Dictionary<String, String>();
        ParentDict.Add("A_1", "1");
        ParentDict.Add("A_2", "2");
        ParentDict.Add("B_1", "3");
        ParentDict.Add("B_2", "4"); 
        ParentDict.Add("C_1", "5");
```

i need to convert this into a new `Dictionary<String, Dictionary<String,String>>`

The result will contain

```
Key                    Value

              Key                   Value             
_________________________________________________

"A"             "A_1"                    "1"
                "A_2"                    "2"

"B"             "B_1"                    "1"
                "B_2"                    "2"

"C"             "C_1"                    "1"
```

Now i'm using `nested for loop` to do this.

How can i do this using `LNQ`or `LAMBDA Expression`?

Comment: Why do you need this data structure?

Comment: The reason I ask is that nested dictionaries are generally slower and less appropriate than single-depth Dictionaries with compound keys or Lookups.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 var result = ParentDict.GroupBy(p => p.Key[0].ToString())
                        .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var result = from p in ParentDict
             group p by p.Key[0] into g
             select new { Key = g.Key, Value = g };
```

This should give you a list of { Key, Value }, where Key will be "A", "B", "C", etc, and Value will be an original instance of KeyValuePair from ParentDict.

You can find more LINQ sample queries on this MSDN page: **[101 Linq Samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746.aspx)**

Answer (score 1):

The reason to do this I suspect is because you need to be able to lookup *all* entries for a particular key-letter.  In that case, a `Lookup` is a better match, generally:

```
var letterLookup = ParentDict.ToLookup(kv=>kv.Key[0]);
```

Usable like this:

```
//letterLookup['A'] is an IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,string>>...

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ",
        letterLookup['A'].Select(kv=>kv.ToString()).ToArray()
    )); // [A_1, 1], [A_2, 2]

Console.WriteLine(new XElement("root",
        letterLookup['B'].Select(kv=>new XElement(kv.Key,kv.Value))
    ));// <root><B_1>3</B_1><B_2>4</B_2></root>


Console.WriteLine(letterLookup['B'].Any()); //true
Console.WriteLine(letterLookup['Z'].Any()); //false
```

The advantage of a lookup over a dictionary is that it may contain multiple values for any given key (unlike a dictionary), and that it has a consistent API if a certain key is absent: it then returns the empty enumerable, whereas a dictionary containing enumerables might either throw KeyNotFoundException, or return null, or return the empty enumerable, all depending on how you created it.

Comment: @ Eamon Nerbonne : oh sorry... thats not the reason( i'm aware of `lookup`) . Actually i requirement is like that .............

Comment: Finally i'll dump the data( in the format of the second dictionary) to an xml file..... (the xml file is having the structure of the second dictionary)

Comment: Added an example with XML output.